# downgrade boost 1.65.1 python to 1.63.1 or uninstall and rebuild

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, downgrade

I have installed `boost 1.65.1` and I want to either downgrade it to `1.63.1` or uninstall it and then rebuild it.

[boost getting started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary)

I don't know how to do that and also from which folder to execute which command...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430332/uninstall-boost-and-install-another-version this might help seem similar

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/397939/how-to-uninstall-boost-1-49-and-install-boost-1-54-in-ubuntu  if you using ubuntu

Comment: Thanks HarshGiri, I'm on Windows 10 sadly. The link you sent has no sure solution but when I tried the command written there I get that `'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Boost_Libraries#Installing_and_Uninstalling_the_Boost_Libraries  for windows

Comment: Hi HarshGiri, I couldn't understand what I should do with the information on that page you provided... I don't have 'boost' in my programs installed on windows so besides that I'm not so how that page is useful..?

Comment: Okay I've deleted all boost versions and managed to install it again so now i'm back to other related problems but i'll post that in a new post. thanks.